# FullText Index on VARBINARY column: how to find string with dot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

On a SQL Server 2012 SP3 CU8 server instance, we have PDF files that have been inserted into a table called `OBJECT_FILE` created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OBJECT_FILE](
    [FILE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FILE_FIN] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OBJ_FILE_IDX_DOCTYPE] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [FILE_TYPE] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [FILE_TXT] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [FILE_TXT_SIZE] [int] NULL DEFAULT ((0)),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_DM_OBJECT_FILE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [FILE_ID] ASC
    )
    WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF, 
        STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
        IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
        ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
        ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
    ) ON [INDEXFG]
) ON [INDEXFG] TEXTIMAGE_ON [BLOBFG]
```

We also created a FullText Index that is built on `FILE_TXT` column, which is a VARBINARY(MAX), created as follows:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX 
ON OBJECT_FILE (
    FILE_TXT TYPE COLUMN OBJ_FILE_IDX_DOCTYPE
) 
KEY INDEX PK_DM_OBJECT_FILE 
WITH STOPLIST=OFF;
```

In that table, we are willing to insert the contents of old documents. In these contents, we will find a unique identifier inserted in the past which follows a naming convention:

```
CORP-MMM-<three_digits_0_to_9>.<three_digits_0_to_9>
```

When I try to do a lookup using CONTAINS built-in function on a particular identifier that I know it exists, it doesn't give me back any results. I use following WHERE clause:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(FILE_TXT,'CORP-MMM-456.245')
```

although a lookup with following WHERE clause provides me multiple results:

```
WHERE CONTAINS(FILE_TXT,'CORP-MMM-456.*')
```

and the record in question can be found with `LIKE`:

```
WHERE FILE_TXT LIKE '%CORP-MMM-456.245%'
```

My question is:

Why can't I get a specific record regarding my WHERE clause and how could I make it work ?

Comment: try to re-build your full-text index

Comment: Do you have a value in `FILE_TXT` column with exact match `CORP-MMM-456.245`?

Comment: @PrabhatG  - it's a brand new Full-Text Index

Comment: @SqlWorldWide - I do have a record that has a FILE_TXT containing CORP-MMM-456.245

Comment: does this return anything ? `WHERE FILETEXT LIKE 'CORP-MMM-456.245'`

Comment: @PrabhatG - Following WHERE clause does: `WHERE FILE_TXT LIKE '%CORP-MMM-456.245%'`

Comment: @RDFozz, what do you mean following WHERE clause: `WHERE CONTAINS(FILE_TXT,'*')`?

Comment: When you use `WHERE CONTAINS(FILE_TXT,'CORP-MMM-456.*')`, you get multiple results - is the `CORP-MMM-456.245` record in those results?

Comment: Well, I get back results and FILE_ID corresponding to `CORP-MMM-456.245`

Comment: OK, what happens if you use `WHERE CONTAINS(FILE_TXT,'CORP-MMM-456 245')`?

Comment: Your proposal leads to following error: `Msg 7630, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Syntax error near '217' in the full-text search condition 'CORP-MMM-456 245'.`. If I add double quotes, I get an empty results set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consisted in the change of the Full-Text Index from English to neutral language.

This can be explained using following `sys.dm_fts_parser` built-in function of SQL Server.

`select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(
    '" dsolkjfdskljfsd dfsd-MMM-236.127 dojfdslfkjds"',
    1033, -- English
    NULL,
    0
) ;`

leads to the deletion of the "." character in keywords:

[image: Full-Text String parsing with Language = English]

while following code keep this character available for lookups:

 `select * from sys.dm_fts_parser(
    '" dsolkjfdskljfsd dfsd-MMM-236.127 dojfdslfkjds"',
    0, -- Neutral
    NULL,
    0
) ;`

Results:

[image: Full-Text String parsing with Language = Neutral]

We dropped existing index and created it using `LANGUAGE 0` option and this solved our problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this might not be an answer but I cannot put this in comment.  Based on the comment by OP @Jefferson (as an answer to my comment) I could not reproduce the behavior.  I can get a record back with where clause exactly matching the value.

I tested this with following code (copied and modified from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e004d207-d0bc-424a-aaf7-9c5fbe641202/full-text-neutral-laguage-word-breaker-perioddot-number-based-search-not-working-different?forum=sqlsearch))

```
CREATE TABLE Department 
   (DepartmentID INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT DepartmentPK PRIMARY KEY, 
    NAME NVARCHAR(50),
    File_txt NVARCHAR(50));
GO
INSERT INTO Department (NAME, File_txt) VALUES ('OP1', 'CORP-MMM-456.245');
INSERT INTO Department (NAME, File_txt) VALUES ('OP2', 'CORP-MMM-456.246');
INSERT INTO Department (NAME, File_txt) VALUES ('OP3', 'CORP-MMM-456.247');
INSERT INTO Department (NAME, File_txt) VALUES ('OP4', 'CORP-MMM-456.245.246');

Go
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG ComplexFTS AS DEFAULT;
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON Department(File_txt LANGUAGE 1033 /* 0 = Neutral, 1033 = American English  */)  
KEY INDEX DepartmentPK WITH (STOPLIST = OFF); /* Or use (stoplist = Off) for no stoplist */
GO
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05';
GO
SELECT * FROM Department WHERE CONTAINS (File_txt,'"CORP-MMM-456.*"');
SELECT * FROM Department  WHERE CONTAINS(File_txt,'CORP-MMM-456.245')
GO
```

This is what I get as my result set.

[image]

Clean up code.

```
DROP FULLTEXT INDEX ON Department;
GO
DROP FULLTEXT CATALOG ComplexFTS;
GO
DROP TABLE Department;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw you set a language during the creation of your Full-Text Index. How could I check for language used for already created Full-Text Index ?

Comment: `sys.fulltext_index_columns` will show that. I also tested with `0=Neutral` and get same result.

Comment: It may be relevant that OP is searching a PDF stored in a `varbinary`, rather than a text column.

Comment: The language_id column is 1033 too...